# Why is my Django server still serving old files after changing filenames and clearing cache?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, python, cache, django

I have made some changes to my Ubuntu server running Django with Apache. I modified some HTML, JS and CSS files,  but nothing has changed.

Things I have tried:

1. Clearing browser cache
2. Renaming files to try and circumvent cache.
3. Ran `manage.py collectstatic`
4. Restarted Apache
5. Rebooted server

I was under the impression that changes to HTML files were reflected immediately in Django, so I am really baffled as to how it could still be serving the old version of the file. I have already checked that there are no duplicated files.

I must be forgetting something. Any ideas, anyone?